# c# Get only numbers from list of strings which contain numbers and words

Tags: c#

I have a list of strings (word--number) ex (burger  5$). I need to extract only numbers from every string in list and make new int list.

Comment: Where does the list come from? Do you have more samples? What is the purpose? What have you tried?

Comment: So why don't you do that?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) method. Hint: You can split using the <space> character to separate the word and number.

Comment: What should happen with "2 patties burger special only available on 31st december for ONLY 5,55$" ?!?

Comment: A list of things you want is not a question; what's your question?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that, Regex and Linq for example.

For short string you can use Linq, for example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var myStringValue = "burger 5$";

    var numbersArray = myStringValue.ToArray().Where(x => char.IsDigit(x));

    foreach (var number in numbersArray)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(numbersArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: As I was clicking on this question, I was thinking the same thing ... Regex, Linq,  Bunch of strings/words, using Linq in such a way is simplest.  I mean, Regex doesn't take much more code.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [Regex.Split, numbers](https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-split-numbers) article.
You'll find the answer in there. Modified code might look like

```
var source = new List<string> {
    "burger 5$",
    "pizza 6$",
    "roll 1$ and salami 2$"
};

var result = new List<int>();

foreach (var input in source)
{
    var numbers = Regex.Split(input, @"\D+");
    foreach (string number in numbers)
    {
        if (Int32.TryParse(number, out int value))
        {
            result.Add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.
Petr

Answer (score 0):

Using `linq` and `Regex`:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(){"burger 5$","ab12c","12sc34","sd3d5"};
Regex nonDigits = new Regex(@"[^\d]");   
List<string> list2 = list.Select(l => nonDigits.Replace(l, "")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look and also solve the problem with this code:

```
  List<string> word_number = new List<string>();
            List<int> number = new List<int>();

            word_number.Add("burger 5$");
            word_number.Add("hamburger 6$");
            word_number.Add("burger 12$");

            foreach (var item in word_number)
            {
                string[] parts = item.Split(' ');

                string[] string_number = parts[1].Split('$');

                number.Add(Convert.ToInt16(string_number[0]));
                Console.WriteLine(string_number[0]);
            }
```